# Cannot create new computer in ADSI Edit on an AD LDS instance

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, adsi, adlds

Using ADSI Edit I cannot use the interface and create a new **computer**.

*Background*

So I installed [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)](http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2017/10/activedirectory-with-vba-part-1.html) on my Windows 8.1 Pro computer.  Then I followed the tutorial to [create an AD LDS instance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725619(v=ws.10).aspx) and then this [tutorial setting up groups and users](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730701(v=ws.10).aspx).  Everything works as detailed in the those tutorial pages.

However, I want to develop LDAP queries to determine the number of computers in a ActiveDirectory group and so I want to create computer objects.  This is not possible from the New menu.   I have read elesewhere that the importing of LDIF matters because you need the right schema.  So I followed the steps a second time and imported all the LDIF files available which are a subset of the files found (for me) in `C:\Windows\ADAM` the selection is ...

- MS-AdamSyncMetadata.LDF
- MS-ADLDS-DisplaySpecifiers.LDF
- MS-AZMan.LDF
- MS-InetOrgPerson.LDF
- MS-MembershipTransitive.LDF
- MS-ParentDistname.LDF
- MS-ReplValMetadataExt.LDF
- MS-SecretAttributeCARs.LDF
- MS-SetOwnerBypassQuotaCARs.LDF
- MS-User.LDF
- MS-UserProxy.LDF
- MS-UserProxyFull.LDF

but even after selecting all of those I still cannot create new computer.

Now, it turns out the only ldf files outside `C:\Windows\ADAM` appear to be SQL Server log data files because the file extension is overloaded.

However, not all the files within `C:\Windows\ADAM` appear on the list, MS-ADAMSCHEMAW2K8.LDF does not appear.  If I poke around in the contents of this file then I can something promising.

```
...
# Class: computer
dn: cn=Computer,cn=Schema,cn=Configuration,dc=X
changetype: ntdsschemaadd
objectClass: classSchema
governsID: 1.2.840.113556.1.3.30
ldapDisplayName: computer
adminDisplayName: Computer
adminDescription: Computer
# schemaIDGUID: bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
schemaIDGUID:: hnqWv+YN0BGihQCqADBJ4g==
objectClassCategory: 1
systemFlags: 16
# subclassOf: user
subclassOf: 1.2.840.113556.1.5.9
...
```

So somehow I cannot select the LDIF file I need.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Continuing to Google, it seems I was correct that *"By default AD LDS schema does not have a computer class"* because this quote appears on this [Technet web page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee617192.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Experimenting with [Extend the AD LDS Schema to Support NFS User Mapping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd764498(v=ws.10).aspx)

Using `ldifde -i -u -f MS-AdamSchemaW2K8.LDF -s localhost:389 -j . -c "cn=Configuration,dc=X" “#configurationNamingContext”` gives the error output below

```
Connecting to "localhost:389"
Logging in as current user using SSPI
Importing directory from file "MS-AdamSchemaW2K8.LDF"
Loading entries.
Add error on entry starting on line 16: Invalid DN Syntax
The server side error is: 0x208f The object name has bad syntax.
The extended server error is:
0000208F: NameErr: DSID-03100225, problem 2006 (BAD_NAME), data 8350, best match of:
    'cn=Schema,"#configurationNamingContext"'

0 entries modified successfully.
An error has occurred in the program
.
```

The above problem is solved by the [answer here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d5e3ac42-f2e4-4aaf-9c80-fc52c436417c/using-ad-lds-with-services-for-nfs?forum=winserverDS) which says do not wrap final term in quotes.

... progressing...and that solved it.  will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So extending the schema is the correct thing to do but understand that the instructions at the canonical [Technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd764498(v=ws.10).aspx) have a typo which is corrected at this [Technet forum Q & A](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/d5e3ac42-f2e4-4aaf-9c80-fc52c436417c/using-ad-lds-with-services-for-nfs?forum=winserverDS).

The correct form is

`ldifde -i -u -f MS-AdamSchemaW2K8.LDF -s localhost:389 -j . -c "cn=Configuration,dc=X" #configurationNamingContext`

Here is proof

[image]